# Oneliner C that prints arguments

Tags: c

I need to write a one liner program that prints out the program's arguments without using any other counter variables except for argc. However:

Problem 1. It prints the arguments in descending order, rather than ascending.

Problem 2. gcc and cl produce different results, so which one is right?

```
while(argc>0) printf("Argument %d is %s\n",--argc,argv[argc]);
```

Comment: Buy a Jigsaw - or wasgij?

Comment: It is possible. Newlines are not needed in a C program. A C program of any length can be put on one line and still be valid. **EXCEPT** Preprocessor stuff cannot be put onto one line; each preprocessor statement will need its own line.

Comment: "Lines" are not mandatory (except for some pre-processing uses) in C. You can write a program (that does not use `#include`) in a single long line.

Comment: You are modifying and using a value (argc) without a sequence point in between. Both compilers are correct and your code is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a oneliner then this will do without the help of `argc`:

```
while(*argv) printf("Argument is %s\n",*argv++);
```

`argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be NULL.

This is also a problem in your code. When you pass `argv[argc]` with `%s`, it causes undefined behaviour. Another being the modification of `argc` without an intervening sequence point.

Answer (score 3):

None is right. Undefined Behaviour is never right.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is neither right nor wrong, simply undefined. Code that invoke undefined behaviour is never portable and rarely bug free.

Answer (score 3):

Move out the `argc` value change from the `printf` otherwise `Undefined Behaviour` occours.

```
while((argc--)>0) printf("Argument %d is %s\n",argc,argv[argc]);
```

The problem was because:

> Order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified

Answer (score 3):

Never write programs this way for there is **no guarantee** which argument will be executed first.

According to C++ standard 5.2.2/8:

> The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the argument expressions are all unsequenced relative to one another. All side effects of argument expression evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered

Either `--argc` or `argv[argc]` will be excuted first and the behavior is undefined.